# Why the audio clip never heard when playing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using Whilefun.FPEKit;

public class RoboSphereWindowBreakInteraction : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public InteractableObjects interactableObjects;
    public AudioClip audioClip;
    public float speed;

    private bool hasStarted = false;
    private Animator anim;

    void Update()
    {
        if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B) || (hasStarted == true)))
        {
            float step = speed * Time.deltaTime; // calculate distance to move
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);

            hasStarted = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.name == "Square 1")
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
            hasStarted = false;
            Destroy(GameObject.Find("Wall_Window_Long_03"));
        }
    }

    public void ActivateRoboSphere()
    {
        foreach(Transform child in transform)
        {
            if(child.name == "Camera")
            {
                RepositionCamera(child);
            }
        }

        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        anim.enabled = true;

        if (!anim.GetBool("Open_Anim"))
        {
            anim.SetBool("Open_Anim", true);

            StartCoroutine(PlayAudio());
        }
        else
        {
            //anim.SetBool("Open_Anim", false);
        }
    }

    private void RepositionCamera(Transform camera)
    {
        var Eyes = GameObject.Find("eyeDome");

        camera.position = Eyes.transform.position + Eyes.transform.forward;
        camera.LookAt(Eyes.transform);
        camera.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = true;
    }

    IEnumerator PlayAudio()
    {
        AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        audio.Play();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(audio.clip.length);
        audio.clip = audioClip;
        audio.Play();
    }
}
```

It's getting inside the PlayAudio but the sound is not heard.

The audio source component screenshot settings :

[image: Audio Source]

Comment: Well. To start with the first play plays whatever was left in there last which at the start is nothing. So maybe it complains? Can’t say I ever tried to play a source with no clip. If that errors it won’t do the rest.   If it’s quiet you might not hear it over anything else. So there’s a lot of potential for it to not be heard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I see with this code is that initially, your audio source's clip isn't set to anything. Thus will result in a null ref exception on this line:

```
 yield return new WaitForSeconds(audio.clip.length);
```

Add a null check and you should be good to go

```
 if (audioSource.clip != null)
 {
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(audioSource.clip.length);    
 }
```